# Selenium webdriver and GDPR consent

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a simple scraper sometime ago which opens up chrome browser and scrapes some data from a website. However now everytime I run that script it does not open the url I provide but instead redirects to GDPR consent website. I removed --incognito mode from options but it is still the same. The chrome opens then the script crashes because it is atuomatically redirected to that GDPR consent webpage.
How can I go around this issue?

Here is the code to reproduce the error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#option.add_argument("--incognito")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriverpath', chrome_options=option)
rval=[]
browser.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL")
timeout = 10
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)
values_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)']")
print(browser)
values = [x.text for x in values_element]
rval.append(values[8])

for title, value in zip(stockname, rval):
    print(title + ': ' + value)

evdict=dict(zip(stockname, rval))
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Im getting `IndexError: list index out of range` on line: `rval.append(values[8])`, which means that this list is empty and it shouldnt be if scraped from that website. But I guess its scraping from the site that it is redirected to (that gdpr consent thing).

Comment: Selenium sessions are stateless, so it will not save cookies or history from previous session, you will need to add steps to handle the new consent page and dismiss it

Comment: Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: NVM I found out: it works with `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='OK']").click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to to bypass such popup window which block selenium from scraping the data I needed to add:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='OK']").click()
```

Which would click on the proper button and close the window for me. Then Selenium works without further problems.